# Tracking Chrome extension events in Analytics

Tags: google-chrome-extension, analytics

Google Chrome Extension documentation has some good information here: 
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_analytics.html

I put the analytics tracking code in my `background.html` file.

However I tried putting the `_gaq.push` call inside a script that runs on the page and got an error saying that the variable `_gaq` is not defined.

So I have to put `onclick` events in every element on the page I want to track and from there, call a function in background.html? Is there a better way to track events?

Comment: What are you trying to track, all click events on all elements?

Comment: No, just the ones for my extension. The average interaction w/ my extension would be about 5 clicks.

Comment: The solution you proposed would be the best one (sending messages to bkgd page which does the actual tracking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `chrome.extension.sendRequest` in the content script and `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` in the `background.html` page. See here for more details: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html. Also be sure your `manifest.json` is correct; I ran into problems when I had a hyphen character instead of an underscore.